# QHttpMultiPart send post request results in "1"

Tags: c++, qt, post, network-programming

I am currently using `QHttpMultiPart` in a Qt Project, but it seems to have some problems on my end ?

I have followed the example and came up with the following code:

```
#include "uploader.h"

#include <QFileInfo>
#include <QMimeDatabase>
#include <QHttpMultiPart>
#include <QNetworkReply>

#include <QDebug>
/**
 * @brief Uploader::Uploader
 * @param parent
 */
Uploader::Uploader(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    uploadInProgress = false;
}

/**
 * @brief Uploader::upload
 * @param absoluteFilePath
 */
void Uploader::upload(QString absoluteFilePath)
{
    qDebug() << "Upload Starting";
    QFileInfo fileInfo(absoluteFilePath);

    QHttpMultiPart *multiPart = new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);

    //action part
    QHttpPart textPart;
    textPart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"cmd\""));
    textPart.setBody(QString("wFile").toLatin1());

    //File Path
    QHttpPart filePathPart;
    filePathPart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"file_path\""));
    filePathPart.setBody(absoluteFilePath.toLatin1());

    //filepart
    QHttpPart filePart;
    QMimeDatabase db;
    QMimeType mime = db.mimeTypeForFile(absoluteFilePath);
    filePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QVariant(mime.name()));
    filePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"preview_file\"; filename=\""+ fileInfo.baseName() + "\""));

    QFile *file = new QFile(absoluteFilePath);
    if ( !file->exists() )
    {
        qDebug() << "File Does not exist";
    }

    file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    filePart.setBodyDevice(file);
    file->setParent(multiPart); // we cannot delete the file now, so delete it with the multiPart

    multiPart->append(textPart);
    multiPart->append(filePathPart);
    multiPart->append(filePart);

    QUrl url("http://project.dbz.dev/index.php?controller=wapi&action=handle");
    QNetworkRequest request(url);


    pManager = new QNetworkAccessManager();

    pReply = pManager->post(request, multiPart);
    multiPart->setParent(pReply);

    connect(pReply, SIGNAL(uploadProgress(qint64,qint64)),this,SLOT(uploadProgress(qint64,qint64)));
    connect(pReply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)), this, SLOT(onError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
    connect(pReply, SIGNAL(finished()),this, SLOT(uploadFinished()));

    // here connect signals etc.
    uploadInProgress = true;
}

/**
 * @brief Uploader::uploadFinished
 */
void Uploader::uploadFinished()
{
    QString data = (QString) pReply->readAll();
    qDebug() << data;
    qDebug() << "Upload finished";

    uploadInProgress = false;
    if ( pReply->error() > 0 )
    {
        qDebug() << "Error occured: " << pReply->error() << " : " << pReply->errorString();
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Upload success";
    }
    delete pReply;
}

void Uploader::uploadProgress(qint64 a, qint64 b)
{
    qDebug() << " SOME PROGRESS!";
    qDebug() << a  << "/" << b;
}

void Uploader::onError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError err)
{
    qDebug() << " SOME ERROR!";
    qDebug() << err;
}
```

Sadly, none of the SLOTS are triggered from the SIGNALS. Neither can I see a package send with wireshark on my local ethernet adapter.
However, my Apache does get a request:

```
192.168.178.21 - - [21/Sep/2013:05:10:41 +0200] "POST /index.php?controller=wapi&action=handle HTTP/1.1" 200 166 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
```

And in my PHP Application I have the following outcome:

```
Application_Controller_WapiController::handleAction: Command: wFile
Application_Controller_WapiController::wFile: POST Request: 1
```

This, basically means, it recognises the Parameter "cmd" and the value "wFile", opens the according PHP action which then does a `print_r($_POST)` which shows me nothing more than a simple 1.

I have no idea what to do. I have looked everywhere on the internet and cannot seem to figure it out. I followed all examples and descriptions on the official documentary and found a couple of threads here on SO. There seemed to be a bug with the QHttpMultiPart class, although it was fixed with the major 5.0.0 update.

tl;dr:

```
connect(pReply, SIGNAL(uploadProgress(qint64,qint64)),this,SLOT(uploadProgress(qint64,qint64)));
    connect(pReply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)), this, SLOT(onError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
    connect(pReply, SIGNAL(finished()),this, SLOT(uploadFinished()));
```

These signals are not being triggered, PHP print_r shows me a 1 and I cannot track the POST request on my machine.

It would be nice if somebody could tell me why the SIGNALS are not emitted and more importantly how I can see a final version of my POST request in my C++ application before it is sent.

Thank you very much! I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved the problem by adding:

```
pELoop = new QEventLoop();
pELoop->exec();
```

Which results into this:
    #include "uploader.h"

```
#include <QFileInfo>
#include <QMimeDatabase>
#include <QHttpMultiPart>
#include <QNetworkReply>

#include <QDebug>
/**
 * @brief Uploader::Uploader
 * @param parent
 */
Uploader::Uploader(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    uploadInProgress = false;
}

/**
 * @brief Uploader::upload
 * @param absoluteFilePath
 */
void Uploader::upload(QString absoluteFilePath)
{
    qDebug() << "Upload Starting";
    QFileInfo fileInfo(absoluteFilePath);

    QHttpMultiPart *multiPart = new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);

    //action part
    QHttpPart textPart;
    textPart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"cmd\""));
    textPart.setBody(QString("wFile").toLatin1());

    //File Path
    QHttpPart filePathPart;
    filePathPart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"file_path\""));
    filePathPart.setBody(absoluteFilePath.toLatin1());

    //filepart
    QHttpPart filePart;
    QMimeDatabase db;
    QMimeType mime = db.mimeTypeForFile(absoluteFilePath);
    filePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QVariant(mime.name()));
    filePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"preview_file\"; filename=\""+ fileInfo.baseName() + "\""));

    QFile *file = new QFile(absoluteFilePath);
    if ( !file->exists() )
    {
        qDebug() << "File Does not exist";
    }

    file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    filePart.setBodyDevice(file);
    file->setParent(multiPart); // we cannot delete the file now, so delete it with the multiPart

    multiPart->append(textPart);
    multiPart->append(filePathPart);
    multiPart->append(filePart);

    QUrl url("http://encryptor.dbz.dev/index.php?controller=wapi&action=handle");
    QNetworkRequest request(url);


    pManager = new QNetworkAccessManager();

    pReply = pManager->post(request, multiPart);
    multiPart->setParent(pReply);

    pELoop = new QEventLoop();
    connect(pReply, SIGNAL(uploadProgress(qint64,qint64)),this,SLOT(uploadProgress(qint64,qint64)));
    connect(pReply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)), this, SLOT(onError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
    connect(pReply, SIGNAL(finished()),this, SLOT(uploadFinished()));

    pELoop->exec();
    // here connect signals etc.
    uploadInProgress = true;
}

/**
 * @brief Uploader::uploadFinished
 */
void Uploader::uploadFinished()
{
    QString data = (QString) pReply->readAll();
    qDebug() << data;
    qDebug() << "Upload finished";

    uploadInProgress = false;
    if ( pReply->error() > 0 )
    {
        qDebug() << "Error occured: " << pReply->error() << " : " << pReply->errorString();
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Upload success";
    }
    pReply->deleteLater();
    pELoop->exit();
}

void Uploader::uploadProgress(qint64 a, qint64 b)
{
    qDebug() << " SOME PROGRESS!";
    qDebug() << a  << "/" << b;
}

void Uploader::onError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError err)
{
    qDebug() << " SOME ERROR!";
    qDebug() << err;
}
```

The request is executed as expected, and the signals are working as well.
I get the output of:

```
Upload Starting 
 SOME PROGRESS! 
16384 / 483753 
 SOME PROGRESS! 
483753 / 483753 
 SOME PROGRESS! 
0 / 0 
"Array
(
    [controller] => wapi
    [action] => handle
    [cmd] => wFile
    [file_path] => D:/Downloads/putty.exe
)
{"cmd":"","status":"","message":"","params":[]}" 
Upload finished 
Upload success
```

I leave this hear in case somebody is looking for a working example.